# Matlab - Can I compute multivariate normal distribution with a covariance matrix with determinant 0?

Tags: matlab

Can I compute multivariate normal distribution with a covariance matrix with determinant 0
in Matlab? In Matlab I currently get Inf values, because the determinant of the covariance
matrix is 0. Is there a mathematical workaround, I am not sure what to do? Or is it just
a dead end, you simply can't compute multivariate normal distribution with such covariance
matrix?

Thanks

Comment: What about the distribution are you trying to compute? Random variates? A CDF? PDF?

Comment: Should that matter at all? But anyway, there is no simple answer, it is part of the code for fitting a factor analyzer. More precisely, it is used for computing the log-likelihood.

Comment: What do you mean there is no simple answer? The answer will depend on what you are trying to do!

Comment: Of course [you can](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition) but you shouldn't expect the number of your independent random variables to match the "size" of the covariance matrix, but rather the rank of the covariance matrix.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you please give more details...